# Average of multiple rows based on column condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I get the average from multiple rows where column stage = 2.

At the moment I am using

```
average = df.loc[df.Stage == 2,'Vout'].mean()
```

However, this returns an average based off the entire column.

I want to have multiple average values based off certain rows, as there is multiple blocks of data.

**Sample Data**
[image: Data Set]

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: How looks expected output from sample data in question?

Comment: I will insert the average values into a new excel sheet.

Comment: You want the mean of rows 5, 7 & 8 (1054, 1031, 1031) separate from the mean of rows 12, 14 & 15 (2, 1046, 1040)?

Comment: Yes @Paul, as there will be multiple blocks of data just like these.

Comment: You will need to assign a specific value to these blocks. so you can group by them, I believe @jezrael did it in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If possible distinguish group by missing values use:

```
df['g'] = df['Stage'].isna().cumsum()

average = df.loc[df.Stage == 2].groupby('g')['Vout'].mean()
```

Comment: Using this I get ``` cannot convert g ```